# Java can't find native libraries when running Clojure JAR

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen, java.library.path

The project I'm working on is a server-side Clojure project with **Leiningen** as my build tool.

The problem occurs when I try to run the JAR I created using **Leiningen**'s uberjar.
The JAR is dependent on some native libraries I've placed in: */usr/lib/nativedeps/so*.

Before I run the JAR I export the environment variable **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** with the native libs path so the linker will know where to look for the native libs:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/ctch/so
```

**And then I run it the JAR:**

```
java -jar externalapibe-0.1.0-standalone.jar 3001
```

**Which throws the exception:**

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JavaASAPSDK in java.library.path

Which means the linker is unable to find **JavaASAPSDK** (which is one of the native libs in */usr/lib/nativedeps/so*) and that I need to specify the lib path in *java.library.path*. So I run:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/nativedeps/so -jar externalapibe-0.1.0-standalone.jar 3001
```

**Which throws the exception:**

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /usr/lib/nativedeps/so/libJavaASAPSDK.so: libprotobuf.so.6: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

Which means the lib **JavaASAPSDK** was found, but another lib called **libprotobuf.so.6** (which **JavaASAPSDK** is dependent on) could not be found.

Problem is both libs are in the same directory!

Any ideas on what can cause this problem and how to solve it???

Comment: What does `ldd` give on the `so` file?

Comment: The LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the question is different from the java.library.path. Intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting:

```
libprotobuf.so.6
```

And creating a symbolic link named 'libprotobuf.so.6' to a library that apparantly was identical to libprotobuf.so.6, named libprotobuf.so.6.0.0.

Then I created a configuration file in: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/

```
touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/externalapibe.conf
```

And wrote the path of my native libs in it:

```
/usr/lib/nativedeps/so
```

Then I ran:

```
ldconfig -v | grep /usr/lib/nativedeps/so
```

Which read the path of my native deps from 'externalapibe.conf' and re-binded the native libs in it.

That seemed to do the work.